# visual studio c inline assembly using funciton arguments in assembly gives c2400 error

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I have a function, in which i following inline assembly is used to set a register, here esp register.

My purpose it to load the esp register with supplied value.

In GCC, it was simple as `_asm("movl stack,%esp")`, which worked in cygwin. But the same in visual studio 2012 not working

```
void set_stack_windows(int stack)
{
    __asm   movl stack,%esp;
}
```

Im getting error as error `C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'stack'`

Comment: @cad, For `void set_stack_windows(int stack)
{
 __asm lea ebx, stack;
 __asm movl [ebx],%esp;
}', now gives ` inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found '['`

Comment: Try removing the percentage sign from `%esp`.

Comment: `mov esp, DWORD PTR [stack]`. Use intel syntax, not AT&T.

Comment: @knm241 Isn't `DWORD PTR` redundant as `esp` already is 32 bits in size?

Comment: @cad, yes it is. I just like using it :)

Comment: @knm241 Oh, I understand. ^^

Comment: See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/02/15/7703995.aspx

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to write the whole function in asm, rather than as inline-asm inside a C function?  Esp. since it messes with the stack.